# How to tweet a picture using Twitter api

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to tweet to Twitter with API. I'm using the library below for this; it works fine with no problems. However, it doesn't work when I want to send a tweet with a picture. How can I do it? I am sharing my submission code below.

The library I use is https://github.com/noweh/twitter-api-v2-php

Related section:

```
 $response = $client->tweet()->performRequest('POST', ['text' => 'This is a unique test tweet.']);

$responseData = json_decode($response->getBody());

if (isset($responseData->data) && isset($responseData->data->id)) {
    echo "Tweet successfully sent! Tweet ID: ". $responseData->data->id;
} else {
    echo "Tweet sending failed: ". $response->getStatusCode();
}
```